# text changing multiple times when hovered for long enough

Tags: html, css

I'm new to coding so apologies, I'm trying to do this thing where a button displays a random fun fact when clicked, but I also wanted to add a feature that, if hovered for long enough, the button text changes up to 3 times (at 3s, 5s, and 8s) and then stays on the last hover (8s one) until clicked, where it comes back to the first non hovered button text. Here's what I was working with. also, if anyone knows of a way to disable antialiasing, that'd be amazing as well

edit: apparently im not the best at explaining. i was looking to change the button text, not the fun fact. fun facts would only appear when clicked, i want the button text (the "click me for a fun fact") to change into 3 other texts when hovered for long enough, so for example, text a would change into text b after 3 seconds, then text b would change into text c after 5 seconds have passed since the hovering started, and then into text d after 8 seconds of constant hovering (so it would only happen after a total of 8 hovering seconds, changing at 3s, 5s and 8s). after that it should stay as text d until clicked. once its clicked, it should return to text a ("click me for a fun fact") and display a random fun fact

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    button {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #c0c0c0;
      border-top: 2px solid white;
      border-left: 2px solid white;
      border-right: 2px solid black;
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-family: yay;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 150px;
      transition: all 0.5s;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: 5px;
    }
    
    button span {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      transition: 0.1s;
    }
    
    .button {
      transition: 0.2s;
    }
    
    .button:hover {
      transition-delay: 3s;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var quotes = [
      'fun fact 1',
      'fun fact 2',
      'fun fact 3',
      'fun fact 4',
      'fun fact 5'
    ]

    function newQuote() {
      var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
      document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
    }
  </script>

  <button onclick="newQuote()">click me for a fun fact</button>
  <div id="quoteDisplay">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If a user leaves hovering after 3 seconds, we should keep the first fun fact instead, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count seconds, setInterval() is here to help, you can do something every x second(s).

In this case, we want to check if the user hovered for 3,5 and 8sec, so we change the `timer` every seconds, when it reaches what we want, we call `newQuotes()`, then stop recording time when our `timer` is over 8sec, or if the user is not hovering the button anymore.

```js
var quotes = [
    'fun fact 1',
    'fun fact 2',
    'fun fact 3',
    'fun fact 4',
    'fun fact 5'
]

var myButtonText = [
  'a button text',
  'another button text',
  'one more button text'
]

var timer=0, timerIdle=false, interval, text=0;

function newQuote() {
  document.getElementById("myButton").innerText = "click me for a fun fact";
  text = 0;
  timer = 0;
  if(quotes.length > 0) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
    document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML =     quotes[randomNumber];
    //Remove item to avoid repetition
    const index = quotes.indexOf(quotes[randomNumber]);
    if(index > -1){
      quotes.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
}

function hoverMe() {
  if(!timerIdle){
    // Do something every 1 second
    interval = setInterval(function(){
      if(timer>8){
        //if timer goes over 8sec, stop doing something on hover
        timerIdle = true;
      } else {
        timer++;
        // if timer == 3,5 or 8 call newQuote();
        if([3,5,8].indexOf(timer) > -1 ) {
          console.log(timer)
          document.getElementById("myButton").innerText = myButtonText[text];
          text++;
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}

// stop the interval if user is not hovering the button
function mouseLeave() {
  clearInterval(interval)
}
```

```css
button {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #c0c0c0;
      border-top: 2px solid white;
      border-left: 2px solid white;
      border-right: 2px solid black;
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-family: yay;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 150px;
      transition: all 0.5s;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: 5px;
    }
    
    button span {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      transition: 0.1s;
    }
    
    .button {
      transition: 0.2s;
    }
    
    .button:hover {
      transition-delay: 3s;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <button id="myButton" onclick="newQuote()" onmouseover="hoverMe()" onmouseleave="mouseLeave()">click me for a fun fact</button>
  <div id="quoteDisplay"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i was looking to change the button text though, not the fun fact. fun facts would only appear when clicked, i want the button text (the "click me for a fun fact") to change into 3 other texts when hovered for long enough, so for example, text a would change into text b after 3 seconds, then text b would change into text c after 5 seconds have passed since first hovered, and then into text d after 10 seconds of constant hovering, and then it should stay as text d until clicked. once its clicked, it should return to text a ("click me for a fun fact")

Comment: I modified my answer, though I am sure you could have easily took the answer and change it to match what you wanted. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below implementation with some explanation

```js
var quotes = [
  'fun fact 1',
  'fun fact 2',
  'fun fact 3',
  'fun fact 4',
  'fun fact 5'
];

var selectedQuote = ""

//shuffle to make it non-duplicated records
function shuffle(array) {
  var i = array.length,
j = 0,
temp;
  while (i--) {
j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
temp = array[i];
array[i] = array[j];
array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}

function newQuote() {

  if (!selectedQuote) {
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
selectedQuote = quotes[randomNumber]
  }
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = selectedQuote;
}

var timer = [3000, 5000, 8000]; //3s, 5s, 8s
var interval;

//generate quotes when a user hovers over the element
function mouseOver() {
  var currentTimerIndex = 0;
  var passedTime = 0;
  var timeStack = 1000;
  var shuffledQuotes = shuffle(quotes); //randomize quotes
  interval = setInterval(function() {
passedTime += timeStack;
if (currentTimerIndex > timer.length - 1) {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = null;
  return;
}
if (timer[currentTimerIndex] <= passedTime) {
  document.getElementById('quoteButton').innerHTML = shuffledQuotes[currentTimerIndex];
  selectedQuote = shuffledQuotes[currentTimerIndex];
  currentTimerIndex++;
}
  }, timeStack)
}

//stop quote generations
function mouseOut() {
  if (interval) {
clearInterval(interval);
interval = null;
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: yay;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.button {
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.button:hover {
  transition-delay: 3s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="newQuote()" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()" id="quoteButton">click me for a fun fact</button>
<div id="quoteDisplay">
</div>
```

Comment: i want the button text to change though (the "click me for a fun fact"). fun facts would only change when clicking the button

Comment: I modified the code again. Could you verify it's your need? @suibaiter

Comment: its giving me an error message messge now, "uncaught typeerror: cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerhtml')" @NickVu

Comment: Ah I forgot to set the id for the button, I just added it in the code. Hopefully, it helps @suibaiter